# Rules of Inscribed Angles

Tags: circles

https://www.dropbox.com/s/chbs2vilr9wjkvz/20140819_130744.jpg

Image of question found above.

I don't understand why angle BCD is formed by tangent and chord and is equal to 1/2 of arc BC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Notice that $\angle OCD = 90 $ as radius $\perp$ tangent

In isosceles $\triangle OCB$ :
$\angle OCB = \dfrac{180 - \angle COB}{2} =  90 - \dfrac{\angle COB}{2} $

Next, use below to solve $\angle BCD$

$\angle OCD =    \angle OCB + \angle BCD = 90$

Comment: The problem says that angle BCD=40.

Comment: Ahh okay so you're trying to find $\angle A$,are you familiar with inscrbed angle formula :  $\text{inscribed angle} =  \dfrac{\text{central angle }}{2}$ ?

Comment: no, I am not familiar. What would the central angle be?

Comment: for this particular problem, $\angle A =  \dfrac{\angle COB}{2} = \angle BCD = 40^{\circ}$

Comment: "central angle" is angle intercepted by arc at the center of circle. see http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~dwiggins/pict44.GIF

Comment: doesn't angle COB=90 degrees?

Comment: nope, $\angle OCD$ equals 90 degrees

Comment: how do you solve for COB?

Comment: $\angle COB$ is the "central angle" for the "inscribed angle" $\angle A$. You knew $\angle A = 40$ , so use the inscribed angle formula

Comment: but I don't know what A equals. finding A is the question.

Comment: Ohhk.. first find angle OCB using :  $ \angle OCB + \angle BCD = 90 $

Comment: OCB=50 degrees then what?

Comment: Find angle COB using the triangle sum property :  $\angle OCB + \angle OBC + \angle COB = 180^{\circ}$

Comment: Note that the triangle is isosceles, so $\angle OCB = \angle OBC = 50$ this gives, $50 + 50 + \angle COB = 180$. solve $\angle COB$

Comment: Why didn't I think of triangle sum property?

Comment: Haha happens :) solving we get : $\angle COB = 80$. appealing to inscribed angle formula gives $\angle A = \dfrac{\angle COB}{2} = \dfrac{80}{2} = 40$

Comment: It is a good formula to memorize :  $\angle BCD = \dfrac{\angle COB}{2}$. This works for ALL chord-tangent intersections